# Data binding (AngularJS) inside JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, data-binding

I'm trying to use data binding inside a `<script>`.

```
<ol class="breadcrumb"></ol>
<div class=heading><h2>{{current.name}}</h2>
...
    <script>
    $(function(){
            $(".breadcrumb").append('<li><a href="#!/categories"> Ledige stillinger</a></li>');
            $(".breadcrumb").append('<li><a href=#!/categories/{{current.keyname}}>{{current.name}}</a></li>');
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

My result is: 
Ledige stillinger (this is ok!) / {{current.name}} (here should it be the name, it works inside h2)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to compile (`$compile`) it with a scope that has the respective properties...

Comment: @PSL I'm not sure what you mean by that, because I havn't used angular so much, but I have used JS/jQuery for simple things.

Answer (score 0):

my answer would be to use AngularJS as it is intended and 1-way bind your DOM to the model values.
if there are multiple elements with the "breadcrumb" class then add these to a collection in your controller's scope and use ng-repeat directive to render them all out then append the "li" tags to this template.

Please see this plunkr example: http://plnkr.co/edit/0T6ldRzSTCnVIKnn3WRh
look at app.js and the following markup:

`<ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="/categories/{{current.keyname}}">{{current.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>`

Comment: JDTLH9 The problem is that `<ol> </ol>` is in index.html, and I want to make the breadcrumbs dynamicly inside a lot of partial pages. So I  need to add it with javascript, but can't access {{current.name}} inside script-tags.

Comment: @AnM It really should not be a problem that the '<ol></ol>' is in the index.html, you should be able to add your ng-controller to the ol tag directly or to a div tag that wraps the ol content. From here you can bind the '<li>' tags as per the plunkr example. Make sense?

Comment: Are you unable to edit the content of index.html to have the ng-app and ng-controller directives on elements that are scoped to contain the '<ol></ol>' tag? If so we could look at bootstrapping the AngularJS app using jQuery, this would work also. I could update the plunkr accordingly for you?

Comment: JDTLH9 I got help from a friend who fixed breadcrumbs, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: No problem at all. Glad that you got sorted :)